# Connect to Ubuntu VirtualBox from Windows with SSH

Tags: networking, ssh, virtualbox

I've read many other similar topics but nothing solved my problem so here it is:

I've installed Ubuntu on Oracle VirtualBox on my Windows 10 machine and now I would like to establish SSH connection between those two systems.

When I try to connect with command `ssh user@127.0.0.1` in return I get the error
`ssh: connect to host 127.0.0.1 port 22: Connection refused`

I have already installed  `openssh-client` and `openssh-server`.

When I use `sudo ufw status verbose`, I get the message: `Status: inactive`.

No matter what I do I get the same error every time.

Comment: There are many ways to do that; what I do is add a second network interface in Host-only mode and use that. I hear that others use port forwarding.

Comment: I would read https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html particularly the table in section 6.2 that indicates which types of networks setups allow communication to/from which destinations.

Answer (score 1):

You should configure network on your guest OS (Ubuntu).

For example, if your main host (Windows 10) connected to router with running DHCP server, on VirtualBox you can create Virtual adapter and configure it as Bridged Networking so that your guest can obtain an IP from your router. As a result you main host and your guest will be on the same local network. After you find out the IP the router assigned to the guest OS you will be able to connect on ssh.